# Hide div and apostrophes occur

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have website with many DIVs. Each contains a single product.

```
<div 
data-id="AAA2"
data-title="Food"
data-bptf-cost="12"
data-hat-cost="12">
```

I would like to remove or hide those with certain names (ex: Food). I'm using code that advised me Marc B (Again - big thanks).

```
$("div[data-title='Food']").hide()
```

Works great, however I'm having a problem with the names in which apostrophes occur. For example, in the code it looks like this:

```
<div 
data-id="AAA2"
data-title="Other&apos;s Stuff">
```

Unfortunately - the elements are not being hidden both while using :

```
$("div[data-title='Other&apos;s Stuff']").hide()
```

and also :

```
$("div[data-title='Other's Stiff']").hide()
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Could you try `div[data-title='Other\\&apos\\;s Stuff']`? (based on http://mothereff.in/css-escapes )

Answer (score 0):

The entitites are converted to characters when inserted into the HTML, so you have to target the characters, not entities

```
$("div[data-title='Other\'s Stuff']").hide();
```

and some special charaters should be escaped, but it doesn't seem like that's an issue here

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6gB4E/1/)

As a sidenote, you have a typo in the second selector, it's not `Stiff`, but `Stuff` ?